# Extract information from multi column output of subprocess.call()?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

How can I extract info from a multi-column output of a subprocess.call() method execution?

I have this command to run:

```
test = subprocess.call('kubectl get ingress -o wide', shell=True)
print(test)
```

It returns response as:

```
NAME      HOSTS     ADDRESS         PORTS     AGE
gateway   *         35.202.20.241   80        52m
```

I want to retrieve ADDRESS column value to get the IP address.

How can I achieve that scenario?

Comment: Please provide more information about device you are extracting IP ADDRESS for.

Comment: it's actually the IP address of Google Container engine's Cluster.

Comment: Are the fields of the output separated by different numbers of space characters or with tabs? Knowing the exact format of the response is an important detail left out of your question.

Comment: I think there's not a defined spaces or tabs between colums.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, the `subprocess.call` function just returns the `errorcode` such as 0, 1, etc., To get the actual output of the command, the `subprocess.check_output` function can be used.

In Shell, `awk` can help greatly in extracting the columns using the column number like `print $3`. To exclude the row header, use condition like `if (NR>1)`.

Here is an example of how it can be achieved.

```
import subprocess
address_col = subprocess.check_output("kubectl get ingress -o wide | awk '{ if(NR>1) print $3; }'", shell=True)
addresses = address_col.splitlines()
print addresses
```

Comment: it returns IP address as `[b'35.202.20.241']` still I need IP from this output, how can I get only IP?